# How to auto-generate simple HTML with model fields?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

With a simple model:

```
class Card(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    good = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

it is possible to generate a form with:

```
class CardForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Card
        fields = '__all__'
```

which then includes **all** the model fields through a simple template with major part as:

```
<table>
  {{ form.as_table }}
</table>
```

But when showing through a `ListView` subclass as:

```
class CardShow(ListView):
    model = Card
    template_name = 'myapp/show.html'
```

it still requires a template where all the model fields are **explicitly** named as:

```
<ul>
  {% for card in object_list %}
    <li>{{ card.name }}, {{ card.rate }}, {{ card.good }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Is there any way to auto-generate HTML code for view (show), just like the form has `form.as_table`, `form.as_p`, and `form.as_ul`?

Comment: What do you mean by `auto-generate`? Do you want just iterate through all fields in model or want some one-tag solution to display your fields?

Comment: @rami: Yes, I see it is a duplicate; thanks.  This also means that there is not easy way for viewing model instance, which is pretty weird when there is a nice way of editing model instance through `ModelForm`.  I will mark for close as duplicate.

Comment: @GwynBleidD: Either could do, but I hoped there was some one-tag solution like for `ModelForm`, but probably not since there was no nice solution to the duplicate pointed out by rami.

Comment: There is no simple solution because for displaying forms there are some standard ways, but for displaying lists - almost every view will do it in different way, depending what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @GwynBleidD: OK, thanks for the clarification.  I am new to Django, so still trying to learn the concepts and common way of doing different tasks.